# Javascript ajax multiple forms of same class using FormData Object

Tags: javascript, ajax, form-data

So I am using the `FormData` object to send files and `POST` data via ajax to my server.
For one form it works fine. But when I have multiple forms with the same class name, no `POST` data is sent. Below is the first working example and the sending, no data is sent.
They are basically the same except the the `FormData` object uses `$form.get(0)`and the second uses `$form`. For the second I've tried `$form.get()`, `$form[0]` to no avail. Am I using `FormData` wrong?

```
EXAMPLE 1
var $form = $('#post-form');
var fd = new FormData($form.get(0));
deferred = $.ajax({
    url: submit_url,
    type: submit_type,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: fd,
    xhr: function() {
        var req = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (req && req.upload) {
            req.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                if(e.lengthComputable) {    
                    var done = e.loaded || e.position, total = e.total || e.totalSize;
                    var percent = parseInt((done/total)*100) + '%';
                    //percentage of uploaded file
                }
            }, false);
        }
        return req;
    },
    beforeSend : function() {
    },
    success : function() {

    }
})


    EXAMPLE 2
    var $form = $('.form-base');
    var fd = new FormData($form);
    deferred = $.ajax({
        url: submit_url,
        type: submit_type,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: fd,
        xhr: function() {
            var req = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (req && req.upload) {
                req.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                    if(e.lengthComputable) {    
                        var done = e.loaded || e.position, total = e.total || e.totalSize;
                        var percent = parseInt((done/total)*100) + '%';
                        //percentage of uploaded file
                    }
                }, false);
            }
            return req;
        },
        beforeSend : function() {
        },
        success : function() {

        }
    })
```

Comment: It says 5 right before the ajax call which is correct. Hmmmm..

Comment: I removed a file input from one of the forms so its down to four, but now it only passes the 1st form first input. I'll have to do some debugging.